# Disable and enable android touchscreen via adb

Tags: android, shell, android-studio, adb, touchscreen

I need to disable and enable touchscreen on my android device. I tried this

```
adb shell su rm -rf /dev/input/event2
```

and

```
adb shell su rm -rf /dev/input/event0
```

but have

```
tmp-mksh: tmp-mksh: - : unknown option
```

What command do I need to send to turn touch screen off and then on?

Comment: is the answer below helping to figuring out the issue?

Comment: *adb shell su -c <cmd>*

Answer (score 3):

I know, much too late for you, but maybe it might help others (as me, who found your thread). This is how it finally worked out for me with separate commands.

- Requires adb root access to be enabled in android dev-settings.
- In the third command, `event1` can even be any other of the events in that folder. From my experience these events restore fully on reboot, so don't hesitate to try deleting them one by one.
- This completely disables touch & access via mouse. However, [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) still works, even with input.

```
    adb root
    adb shell
    rm -rf /dev/input/event1
```